# Why can’t I implicitly convert with var?

Tags: c#, constants, var, implicit-conversion

(my questions refer to the code written below)

Why can’t I implicitly convert type int[] into var[]? I know you can’t implicitly assign var and const. But why? The compiler is literally telling me ”Cannot implicitly convert type int[] into var[].”

If the computer already knows what I intend, they why doesn’t it just do it? Will future IDEs, compilers, visual studio (don’t know which one to use) automatically convert it one day for you in C#? Or is there a reason you cannot convert it? Hoping that I can learn *the why*.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var[ ] a = new int[10];
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            a[k] = k*2;
        }
        foreach (int k in a) {
            Console.WriteLine(k);
        }
    }
}
```

(code source sololearn)

My last question is just curiosity. (like the example above) Does day to day programming look so much different than the textbooks? I understand textbooks are critical to learning the theory and having understanding.

Comment: just do var a = new int[10]

Comment: `var[]` is not a thing in C#. Just `var` will do here.

Comment: var is not a type, You just let the compiler conclude what real type it stands for. If the conclusion is not possible or not unique, it will tell you. Array of var makes no sense. It's more a syntactic thing, kind of preprocessor.

Comment: Thank you all. I guess syntax is a big deal. :)

Answer (score 2):

`var` is a keyword, not a type, therefor you can't have an array of `var`.

The `var` keyword simplifies the code by saving you the need to declare the specific data type, instead letting the compiler infer it from the variable assignment.

Therefor, `var[ ] a = new int[10];` should simply be changed to `var a = new int[10];`

Answer (score 1):

There error you state is actually a *secondary* error. The *primary* error is:

> The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found

It is assuming you're using `var` as a type, like you would use `int` or `short` et al.

The correct syntax is:

```
var a = new int[10];
```

Which works just fine with your code.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate it.